# GObject subclassing in C unable to create a subclass instance

Tags: c, glib, gobject

I wanted to try the GObject API. The idea is to create a Vehicule class which is a `DERIVABLE` type and create a subclass of Vehicule called Car which is a `FINAL` type. My problem is that when I try in a little program to create a class Car, my program block and doesn't return at the instance creation.

Here is the minimum code in order to reproduce my problem. I use the convention tuto-vehicule /tuto-car.

*tuto-vehicule.h*

```
#ifndef __TUTO_VEHICULE_H__
#define __TUTO_VEHICULE_H__
#include <glib-object.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

typedef struct _TutoVehiculePrivate {
    GObject parent_instance;
    GString *name;
    guint nb_wheels;
} TutoVehiculePrivate;

typedef struct _TutoVehiculeClass {
    GObjectClass parent_class;
} TutoVehiculeClass;

#define TUTO_TYPE_VEHICULE tuto_vehicule_get_type()
G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE(TutoVehicule, tuto_vehicule, TUTO, VEHICULE, GObject);


TutoVehicule *tuto_vehicule_new (void);

void tuto_vehicule_set_name(TutoVehicule *self, gchar *name);
void tuto_vehicule_set_nb_wheels(TutoVehicule *self, gint nb_wheels);
void tuto_vehicule_print_name(TutoVehicule *self);
void tuto_vehicule_print_nb_wheels(TutoVehicule *self);

G_END_DECLS

#endif
```

*tuto-vehicule.c*

```
#include "tuto-vehicule.h"
#include <stdio.h>

G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_PRIVATE(TutoVehicule, tuto_vehicule, G_TYPE_OBJECT);

static void
tuto_vehicule_dispose(GObject *object)
{
    TutoVehiculePrivate *priv = tuto_vehicule_get_instance_private(TUTO_VEHICULE(object));
    printf("tuto_vehicule_dispose\n");
    g_string_free(priv->name, TRUE);
    G_OBJECT_CLASS(tuto_vehicule_parent_class)->dispose(object);
}

static void
tuto_vehicule_class_init(TutoVehiculeClass *klass)
{
    GObjectClass *g_object_class = G_OBJECT_CLASS(klass);
    /* instance destructor*/
    g_object_class->dispose = tuto_vehicule_dispose;
    printf("tuto_vehicule_class_init for TutoVehiculeClass created by G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE\n");
}

static void
tuto_vehicule_init(TutoVehicule *self)
{
    TutoVehiculePrivate *priv = tuto_vehicule_get_instance_private(self);
    priv->name = g_string_new(NULL);
    priv->nb_wheels = 0;
    printf("tuto_vehicule_init\n");
}

TutoVehicule *
tuto_vehicule_new(void)
{
    TutoVehicule *vehicule_instance = g_object_new(TUTO_TYPE_VEHICULE, NULL);
    return vehicule_instance;
}

void tuto_vehicule_set_name(TutoVehicule *self, gchar *name)
{
    TutoVehiculePrivate *priv = tuto_vehicule_get_instance_private(self);
    g_string_assign(priv->name, name);
}

void tuto_vehicule_set_nb_wheels(TutoVehicule *self, gint nb_wheels)
{
    TutoVehiculePrivate *priv = tuto_vehicule_get_instance_private(self);
    priv->nb_wheels = nb_wheels;
}

void tuto_vehicule_print_name(TutoVehicule *self)
{
    TutoVehiculePrivate *priv = tuto_vehicule_get_instance_private(self);
    printf("Vehicule name: %s\n", priv->name->str);
}

void tuto_vehicule_print_nb_wheels(TutoVehicule *self)
{
    TutoVehiculePrivate *priv = tuto_vehicule_get_instance_private(self);
    printf("Vehicule number of wheels: %d\n", priv->nb_wheels);
}
```

*tuto-car.h*

```
#ifndef __TUTO_CAR_H
#define __TUTO_CAR_H
#include "tuto-vehicule.h"
#include <glib-object.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

#define TUTO_TYPE_CAR tuto_car_get_type ()
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE(TutoCar, tuto_car, TUTO, CAR, TutoVehicule);

typedef struct _TutoCar {
    TutoVehicule parent_instance;
} TutoCar;

TutoCar *tuto_car_new(void);
void tuto_car_print_name(TutoCar *self);
void tuto_car_print_nb_wheels(TutoCar *self);
G_END_DECLS
#endif
```

*tuto-car.c*

```
#include "tuto-car.h"
#include <stdio.h>

G_DEFINE_TYPE(TutoCar, tuto_car, TUTO_TYPE_CAR);

static void
tuto_car_class_init(TutoCarClass *klass)
{
    printf("tuto_car_class_init\n");
}

static void
tuto_car_init(TutoCar *self)
{
    printf("tuto_car_init\n");
}

TutoCar *
tuto_car_new(void)
{
    TutoCar *car = g_object_new(TUTO_TYPE_CAR, NULL);
    tuto_vehicule_set_name(TUTO_VEHICULE(car), "car");
    tuto_vehicule_set_nb_wheels(TUTO_VEHICULE(car), 4);
    return car;
}

void
tuto_car_print_name(TutoCar *self)
{
    tuto_vehicule_print_name(TUTO_VEHICULE(self));
}

void
tuto_car_print_nb_wheels(TutoCar *self)
{
    tuto_vehicule_print_nb_wheels(TUTO_VEHICULE(self));
}
```

I use those two classes in a simple main file :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tuto-vehicule.h"
#include "tuto-car.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Create a TutoVehicule instance\n");

    TutoVehicule *moto = tuto_vehicule_new();
    printf("Puts its name to moto\n");
    tuto_vehicule_set_name(moto, "moto");
    printf("Puts its number of wheels to 2\n");
    tuto_vehicule_set_nb_wheels(moto, 2);

    printf("Create a TutoCar instance\n");
    TutoCar *car = tuto_car_new();

    printf("Use methods instance\n");

    tuto_vehicule_print_name(moto);
    tuto_vehicule_print_nb_wheels(moto);

    tuto_vehicule_print_name(TUTO_VEHICULE(car));
    tuto_vehicule_print_nb_wheels(TUTO_VEHICULE(car));

    tuto_car_print_name(car);
    tuto_car_print_nb_wheels(car);

    printf("Destroy the instances created previously\n");
    g_object_unref(car);
    g_object_unref(moto);

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation works with :

```
gcc -Wall -o main_vehicule `pkg-config --libs --cflags gobject-2.0` main_vehicule.c tuto-car.c tuto-vehicule.c
```

But when I run the program, as I said below, I have this ouput and the program block without returning nor emitting error messages:

```
Create a TutoVehicule instance
tuto_vehicule_class_init for TutoVehiculeClass created by G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE
tuto_vehicule_init
Puts its name to moto
Puts its number of wheels to 2
Create a TutoCar instance
```

I know that my program block at this statement:

```
TutoCar *car = g_object_new(TUTO_TYPE_CAR, NULL);
```

What have I missed? The official docs are not really clear.

**edit**

Here is a gdb session:

```
(gdb) break tuto-car.c:tuto_car_new
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400dcb: file tuto-car.c, line 21.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/cedlemo/Projets/C/GObject/derivable_type/main_vehicule 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
Create a TutoVehicule instance
tuto_vehicule_class_init for TutoVehiculeClass created by G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE
tuto_vehicule_init
Puts its name to moto
Puts its number of wheels to 2
Create a TutoCar instance

Breakpoint 1, tuto_car_new () at tuto-car.c:21
21      TutoCar *car = g_object_new(TUTO_TYPE_CAR, NULL);
(gdb) backtrace
#0  tuto_car_new () at tuto-car.c:21
#1  0x0000000000400c02 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at main_vehicule.c:16
(gdb) next
```

The program block in gdb too so I had to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and inspect the stack:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff75ba269 in syscall () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff790618f in g_cond_wait () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff78e8437 in g_once_init_enter () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x0000000000400d1e in tuto_car_get_type () at tuto-car.c:4
#4  0x0000000000400d44 in tuto_car_get_type () at tuto-car.c:4
#5  0x0000000000400dd0 in tuto_car_new () at tuto-car.c:21
#6  0x0000000000400c02 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at main_vehicule.c:16
```

Comment: please take heed of the following: "note that symbols starting with double underscore, or underscore and a capital letter, are unconditionally reserved for the implementation. Yes, system headers use names with double underscores — they're part of the implementation and aren't allowed to pollute your namespace. You shouldn't pollute their namespace. For all practical purposes, and multiple counter-examples notwithstanding, treat names starting with underscore as reserved for the compiler. "

Comment: @user3629249, if you are refering to _TutoCar or _TutoVehiculePrivate for example, I am just following the GObject convention see : https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.48/howto-gobject.html  or https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.48/howto-gobject-code.html

Comment: I realize, this really is pretty much a minimal example as GObject code is sadly verbose; you could make it more minimal by cutting out the name and number of wheels properties, and see if that affects anything. In any case, I would use a debugger to see where the program is _really_ freezing, instead of relying on print statements. For now, I will vote to reopen as I think the problem statement is clear.

Comment: I have added some gdb informations .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :

in the file tuto-car.c, I a the line :

```
G_DEFINE_TYPE(TutoCar, tuto_car, TUTO_TYPE_CAR);
```

for the two macros :

- `G_DEFINE_TYPE`
- `G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_PRIVATE`

the last parameter is the GType of the parent. In my code I used the GType of the class it self. I should have used `TUTO_TYPE_VEHICULE`

```
G_DEFINE_TYPE(TutoCar, tuto_car, TUTO_TYPE_VEHICULE);
```

With this the previous code is fully working.